# . Как узнать из-за кого блокируется пользователь при ошибочном вводе пароля?

Tags: sql, oracle

В последнее время очень часто стал блокироваться пользователь. Подозреваю, это из-за ошибочного ввода логина и пароля, но не знаю как выяснить, с какого компютера это происходить.

Можно ли получить какую-либо информацию по этому поводу, например, IP или имя пользователя, из-за которого заблокировался пользователь?

---

PS Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: А на сколько раз у вас установлен параметер FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS в профиле?

Comment: @0xdb  параметр FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 10

Comment: Audit у вас включен, если да, то как?

Comment: @0xdb аудит был выключен. я выставил в настройках параметр audit_trail = db и перезагрузил Теперь . audit_sys_operations - FALSE, audit_file_dest -  E:\ORACLE\.......\ADUMP , audit_trail - DB. Я так полагаю надо подождать блокировки и посмотреть dba_audit_trail

Comment: Не забыли выполнить - `audit create session whenever not successful;`? Думаю, ждать не стоит, залогиньтесь с заведомо неверным паролем 10 раз и посмотрите.

Comment: @0xdb Да, все получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: @0xdb Ничего недостоверного не указывал. по второй ссылке есть упоминание этого файла. https://www.oradba.ch/2011/05/database-audit-and-audit-trail-purging/  . Ответ как компиляция из прочитанного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если аудит не настроен, то простое решение - создать [системный триггер](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-AC093015-E9EA-47B1-8B0C-51A1860AB12D) на ошибки БД:

```
create table failedlogons (
    dt date, dbuser varchar2 (32), osuser varchar2 (32), 
    host varchar2 (64), ip varchar2 (24), memo varchar2 (256))
/
create or replace trigger failedlogonstrig after servererror on database
begin
    if ora_is_servererror (1017) then
        insert into failedLogons values (
            sysdate,
            sys_context ('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY'), 
            sys_context ('USERENV', 'OS_USER'), sys_context ('USERENV', 'HOST'), 
            sys_context ('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'), 'failed logon');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Каждая попытка подключения с неверным паролем будет запротоколирована. Когда надобность в протоколировании этого события отпадёт, то можно просто удалить триггер и таблицу.

```
$ sqlplus -l me/xxx@dbsrv/pdb1
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

$ sqlplus -l sys/Pass@dbsrv/pdb1

SQL> select * from failedlogons;

DT        DBUSER OSUSER HOST             IP               MEMO
--------- ------ ------ ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
01-DEC-20 ME     me     LOCAL\MYNAME     192.168.1.111    failed logon

SQL> drop table failedLogons purge;
SQL> drop trigger failedLogonsTrig;
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Попробую и этот метод

Comment: Это метод действительно лучше чем аудит, т.к не  забивает таблицу dba_audit_tra. Проверил . Все работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Мои действия:

1. Выставил параметр `audit_trail`:

   ```
   alter system set audit_trail='DB' scope=spfile;`
   ```
2. Перезапустил службу Oracle
3. Выполнил:

   ```
   audit create session whenever not successful;
   ```
4. Затем запросом:

   ```
   select * 
   from dba_audit_trail where returncode in (1017, 28000) 
   order by timestamp desc;
   ```

   получаю всю необходимую информацию по заблокированному пользователю.